# After installing Catalyst Center, my Ubuntu 13.10 has changed user password

Tags: 13.04, radeon

I tried installing two fresh installs, but every time i restart I'm asked for a password as usual. But the one i have used to have doesn't work. It's a Radeon HD 4530 card.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot into recovery mode by pressing Shift after bios screen. From there you can get a root prompt and from there you can change the password with the command:

`passwd iveralvik`